# Sefaradi Hashkafa of Musar

Tags: sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, mussar-ethics

There are various Hashkafot in regards to Mussar from Rav Yisrael Salanter's Derech to the Hassidic Musar based Sefarim (most Chassidishe Sefarim are Musar). What's an example of Sefaradi Musar Derech?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, I believe that the Ramhal, the author of Mesilat Yeshiraim, was sephardi.

Comment: Kaf Hachaim by Rav Chaim Palagi

Comment: @Ramin you're not mistaken but that's not an entire Hashkafa that's a section of Mussar which applies to everyone. The Chassidim and the Litvish have an entire Hashkafa.

Comment: @sam that's a good answer but I'm looking for more.

Comment: More of what?......

Comment: @sam that's not an entire Hashkafa that's a section of Hadracha in some topics of life.

Comment: Its a nice amount....

Comment: @sam I used to read that Sefer everyday and I disagree.

Comment: Ok.................

Comment: @sam I hope you forgive me.

Comment: @hacham Gabriel , not necessary,I am not upset,I respect what you have to say.

Comment: @sam what I would love would be an expanded edition of Pele Yoetz.

Answer (score 5):

There are many Sephardi works of mussar. In fact, the first books of mussar were written by Sepharadim. Here's are some:

- Rambam's *Hilkhot Deot* from his Mishneh Torah
- Avraham ben Rambam's *Hamaspik LeOvdei Ha'*
- Rav Bahya's *Chovot HaLevavot*
- Rav Yonah's *Shaarei Teshuvah*
- Rav Isaac Aboav's *Menorat HaMaor*
- Rav Palagi's *Kaf HaHaim*
- Chida's *Avodat HaKodesh*
- Rav Eliyahu de Vidas's *Reishit Hokhmah*
- Ramak's *Tomer Devorah*
- Rav Eliezer Papo's *Pele Yoetz*
- Rav Elazar Ezkari's *Sefer Hareidim*
- Rav Eliyahu HaCohen's *Shevet Mussar*
- Ben Ish Hai's *Maim Hayim*

Comment: Nice list. Also consider adding המספיק לעובדי ה by [R' Avraham ben HaRambam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_ben_Moses_ben_Maimon).

Comment: There are a million books of Musar, but not Musar Hashkafa. The only thing close to what I wanted is Pele Yoetz but there is not enough information on each topic for my liking.

Comment: @Fred Hamaspik is a very interesting Sefer Derech Agav. It's an interesting Derech in Avodat Hashem.

Comment: @HachamGabriel If these aren't examples of Sephardi Mussar that you're looking for, you should define what you mean by Musar Hashkafa.

Comment: I know there are Sefaradi Sefarim on Musar. I'm asking for an entire philosophy of life, not just specific topics.

Comment: A couple items from the list should be removed that arent "the first" mussar books The Pele Yoetz was 18th-19th century. R. Chaim Palagi lived in the 19th century. Ben Ish Chai lived even later into the 20th century. Even the Shevet Mussar lived the better part of a millenium after the Chovos Halevavos; hardly the earliest.

Comment: @mevaqesh The list isn't meant to show the first mussar books. In my answer, I simply meant that the first books of mussar were written by Sephardim, and some of those books are on the list. The question was on Sephardic mussar without reference to history.

Comment: Adding a few words to the post would make that clearer.