# Is there a master list(s) of Middot?

Tags: jewish-books, mussar-ethics, middos-character-traits

I am looking to find a master list of Middot. I suspect different texts have different lists: ie Cheshbon Ha Nefesh has one list and maybe other sefarim have other lists. At this stage of my research I am hoping to get a list of the possible options of Middot. Any help with this would be deeply appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a working definition of “middot” such that we can determine what would be on the master list?

Comment: I've seen a list of 70 character traits assembled by Vilna Gaon. Not sure where to find it.

Comment: There are many *middos* discussed in *Pele Yo'eitz* 
 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/37833

Answer (score 9):

The **[Sefer Orchos Tzaddikim](https://www.sefaria.org/Orchot_Tzadikim)** speaks about the following character traits:

גאוה - Pride/Arrogance

ענוה - Humility

בושה - Shame

עזות - Brazenness

אהבה - Love

שנאה - Hate

רחמים - Mercy

אכזריות - Cruelty

שמחה - Happiness

דאגה - Worry / Anxiousness

חרטה - Regret

כעס - Anger

רצון - Will / Desire

קנאה - Jealousy

זריזות - Zealousness

עצלות - Laziness

נדיבות - Generosity

ציקנות - Stinginess

זכירה - Memory

שכחה - Forgetfulness

שתיקה - Quietness

שקר - Lying / Falsehood

אמת - Truthfulness

חניפות - Flattery

---

Additionally, **[Mesilas Yesharim](https://www.sefaria.org/Mesilat_Yesharim)** speaks about some of these as well as:

זהירות - Watchfulness / Cautiousness

זהירות - Cleanliness

פרישות - Separation

טהרה - Purity

חסידות - Piety

יראה - Fear (specifically Fear of G-d)

קדושה - Holiness

---

Off the top of my head further middos are:

תאוה - Desire

כבוד - Honour (For these two refer to [Pirkei Avos 4:21](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.4.21?ven=Mishnah_Yomit_by_Dr._Joshua_Kulp&vhe=Torat_Emet_357&lang=bi))

אֵיבָה - Hate (different to שנאה as mentioned above)

הִתּוּל \ לֵצָנוּת - A person who scoffs / scoffer

רְדִיפַת הַמָּמוֹן \ רְדִיפַת הַמַּאֲכָלוֹת - Greed (for money) / Greed (for food) - Refer to [Mishneh Torah - Teshuva 7:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Repentance.7.3?ven=Maimonides%27_Mishneh_Torah,_edited_by_Philip_Birnbaum,_New_York,_1967&vhe=Torat_Emet_363&lang=bi&lookup=%D7%A8%D6%B0%D7%93%D6%B4%D7%99%D7%A4%D6%B7%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D6%B7%D7%9E%D6%BC%D6%B7%D7%90%D6%B2%D7%9B%D6%B8%D7%9C%D7%95%D6%B9%D7%AA&with=Lexicon&lang2=en)

רשעות - Wickedness (refer to [Yechezkel 33:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezekiel.33.19?ven=Tanakh:_The_Holy_Scriptures,_published_by_JPS&vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang=bi))

ארך אפים & חנון - Slowness to anger & Graciousness (also know as חן) - as per the [13 middos of Hashem](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.34.6?ven=The_Contemporary_Torah,_Jewish_Publication_Society,_2006&vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0)

גבורה - Might (the trait of Yitzchak)

Also worth noting Rambam's [Shmoneh Perakim 4:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Eight_Chapters.4.2?ven=The_Eight_Chapters_of_Maimonides_on_Ethics,_by_Joseph_I_Gorfinkle&lang=bi&lookup=%D7%A1%D7%9C%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%9C&with=Lexicon&lang2=en) which defines how to have a balanced character and the range in which such traits sit and resultantly lists other traits that might be of interest:

> וכן הנדיבות ממוצע בין **הכילות והפזור**, והגבורה ממוצעת בין **המסירה לסכנות** ובין **רך הלבב**, ו**הסלסול** ממוצע בין **ההתנשאות** ובין **הנבלה**, והענוה ממוצעת בין הגאוה ו**שפלות הרוח**, וה**הסתפקות** ממוצע בין אהבת הממון והעצלה, וטוב לב ממוצע בין **הנבלה ויתרון טוב הלבב**, (ומפני שאין למדות האלה שם ידוע בלשננו צריך לפרש ענינים ומה שרוצים בו הפילוסופים, לב טוב קורים מי שכל כוונתו להטיב לבני אדם בגופו ובממנו ועצתו בכל יכולתו בלתי שישיגהו נזק או בזיון והוא האמצעי, הנבל הוא הפך זה והוא מי שאינו רוצה להועיל לבני אדם בדבר אפילו במה שאין בגו חסרון ולא טורח ולא נזק, והוא הקצה האחרון, ויתרון טוב הלבב הוא שעושה הדברים הנזכרים בלב טוב, ואפילו אם ישיגהו בזה נזק גדול או בזיון או טורח רב או הפסד מרובה, והוא הקצה הראשון), **והסבלנות** ממוצע בין הכעס והעדר **הרגשת חרפה ובוז**, ובושת פנים ממוצע בין העזות והביישנות
>
> Likewise, liberality is the mean between **sordidness** and **extravagance**; courage, between **recklessness** and **cowardice**; **dignity**, between **haughtiness** and **loutishness**; humility, between arrogance and **self-abasement**; **contentedness**, between **avarice** and **slothful indifference**; and **magnificence**, between **meanness** and **profusion**. [Since definite terms do not exist in our language with, which to express these latter qualities, it is necessary to explain their content, and tell what the philosophers meant by them. A man is called magnificent whose whole intention is to do good to others by personal service, by money, or advice, and with all his power, but without meanwhile bringing suffering or disgrace upon himself. That is the medium line of conduct. The mean man is one who does not want others to succeed in anything, even though he himself may not thereby suffer any loss, hardship, or injury. That is the one extreme. The profuse man, on the contrary, is one who willingly performs the above-mentioned deeds, in spite of the fact that thereby he brings upon himself great injury, or disgrace, terrible hardship, or considerable loss. That is the other extreme.] **Gentleness** (*I would translate as Patience*) is the mean between anger and **insensibility to shame and disgrace**; and **modesty**, between impudence and shamefacedness. (Sefaria translation)

Comment: Dov this is amazing. Thank you so much.

Comment: Pleasure! (15 chars)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the biggest and most detailed list of Mussar middot online and incorporates most of the middos mentioned in the previous excellent recommendations: https://www.mussar.center/lists/middot

I hope this helps!

Comment: At the moment this answer is styled in a way that it is just promoting your website and is likely to be treated as spam. If you want to actively contribute - provide answers not just links please.

Comment: @Dov I see, thank you for letting me know. Although, is it possible it's not "just" promoting a website? I believe the list there is the best answer to the question. Maybe if the contents were shared directly here in one form or another instead of just the link?

Comment: Correct - if beside the link you list some relevant highlights that would make it into a perfectly acceptable answer (FYI I didn't downvote). A bit like you did in your answer on mussar seforim for women.

Comment: This is wonderful, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sefer Hamidot - aka Sefer ha-Alef Bet by R' Nachman of Breslev

https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA_(%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%A1%D7%9C%D7%91)

> אבידה | אהבה | אכילה | אלמן | אמונה | אמת | ארץ ישראל | בגדים | בושה | בטחון | בית | בכייה | בנים | ברכה | בשורה | גאוה | גניבה וגזילה | דיין | דעת | דרך | הוראה | הכנסת אורחים | המתקת דין | הצלחה | הרהורים | הרחקת רשעים | הריון | התבודדות | התנשאות | ודוי דברים | ותרן | זיפן |זכות אבות | זכירה | זקנים | זריזות | חדושין דאוריתא | חיתון | חלום | חן | חנפה | חקירה | טבע | טהרה | טלטול | יחוס | יראה | ישועה | כבוד | כישוף | כעס | לימוד | ליצנות | לשון הרע | מוהל | ממון | מסור | מפורסם | מפלת | מריבה | משיח | משקה | נגינה | נדה | נהנה מאחרים | ניאוף | ניבול פה | ניסיון | נפילה | נר תמיד | סגולה | סוד | ספירת העומר | ספר | עבירה | עונש | עזות | ענוה | עצבות | עצה | עצירות | עצלות | פוסק | פחד | פידיון שבויים | פרישות | צדיק |צדקה |קליפה | קללה | קנאה | קרי | קשוי לילד | ראיה | רחמנות | רפואה | שבועה | שבת | שוחד | שוחט | שינה | שכרות | שלום | שמחה | שרים | תוכחה | תפילה | תשובה

https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Translation:Sefer_Hamidot

```
עצות AITZOT -- ADVICE
זכות אבות ZICHUS UVOS -- ANCESTRAL MERIT
כעס KAASS -- ANGER
גאוה GAAVA -- ARROGANCE
נהנה מאחרים DERIVING BENEFIT FROM OTHERS
משקה MASHKE -- BEVERAGES
ברכה BRACHAH -- BLESSING
ספר SEFER -- BOOK
עזות AZUS -- BRAZENNESS
שחד SHOACHAD -- BRIBERY
צדקה TZEDUKA -- CHARITY
תוכחה TOACHACHAH -- CHASTISEMENT
בנים CHILDREN
בגדים CLOTHES
דעת DA`AT -- COGNIZANCE
פוסק CODIFIERS OF THE LAW
ודוי דברים CONFESSION
מריבה CONTENTION
עצירות CONSTIPATION
בכיה CRYING
קללה CURSE
ותרן one who DEFERS
עצבות DEPRESSION
קשוי לילד DIFFICULTY IN CHILDBIRTH
הרחקת רשעים HARCHUKAS RISHUIM -- DISTANCING THE WICKED
חלום DREAM
שכרות DRUNKENNESS
אכילה EATING
זקנים THE ELDERLY
אמונה FAITH
מפרסם FAMED
פחד FEAR
יראה FEAR OF G-D
חנפה ADULATION
נבול פה FOUL LANGUAGE
נפילה FALLING
חן FAVOR/CHARM/GRACE
זיפן FORGER
רפואה HEALING
התבודדות HISBODIDUS (seclusion — often implying to be alone in communion with the Lord)
התנשאות HIGH POSITION/GREATNESS
כבוד HONOR
הוראה HORA'AH -- INSTRUCTION
הכנסת אורחים HOSPITALITY
בית HOUSE
ענוה HUMILITY
קלפה HUSKS (EVIL FORCES)
מסור INFORMER
חקירה INVESTIGATION
ארץ ישראל ISRAEL
קנאה JEALOUSY
שמחה JOY
דיין JUDGE
נר תמיד MEMORIAL (lit CONSTANT) LAMP
עצלות LAZINESS
למוד LEARNING
יחוס LINEAGE
אהבה LOVE
אבידה LOST ARTICLE
קרי KERI (Emission of Seed)
חתון MARRIAGE
משיח MASHIACH (MESSIAH)
זכירה MEMORY
נדה MENSTRUAL IMPURITY
רחמנות MERCY
מפלת MISCARRIAGE
ליצנות MOCKERY
מוהל MOHEL (One Who Performs a Circumcision)
ממון MONEY
נגינה MUSIC
טבע NATURE
חידושין דאורייתא NOVELTIES OF TORAH
שבועה OATH
שרים OFFICIALS
ספירת העמר THE COUNTING OF THE OMER
שלום PEACE
תפלה PRAYER
הריון PREGNANCY
ענש PUNISHMENT
טהרה PURITY
פדיון שבויים REDEEMING PRISONERS
תשובה REPENTANCE
שוחט SHOCHET -- KOSHER SLAUGHTERER
ישועה SALVATION
סוד SECRET
סגולה SEGULAH (an Auspicious Action or Object)
נאוף SEXUAL IMMORALITY
שבת SHABBAT (the Sabbath)
בושה SHAME
עברה SIN
לשון הרע SLANDER
שינה SLEEP
הצלחה SUCCESS
המתקת דין SWEETENING OF JUDGMENTS
נסיון TEST
גנבה וגזלה THEFT (secretly or openly)
הרהורים THOUGHTS
בשורה TIDING
דרך TRAVEL (a way)
בטחון TRUST (in G-d)
אמת TRUTH
צדיק TZADDIK
ראיה VISION
טלטול WANDERING (having to move constantly from place to another)
אלמן WIDOWER
כשוף SORCERY
זריזות ZEAL
```

Comment: Thank you, Nissim!

Comment: Guess how many midot are in this list? קח 108 gematria נ נח  Na Nach! A friend told me the late Sagi Yosef was the first to point this out.